# How to read a user's newsfeed with fql

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-fql

I'm using the query suggested in Facebook API reference:

"SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me() AND type = 'newsfeed')"

I get most of the items that I see in my "Home" feed on Facebook but not all of them. Any idea why?

Comment: If you have a helpful answer you should accept it. Click on checkmark under upvote/downvote counter. This will mark the question as "answered" and provide you with small reputation bonus. See [How do I ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) FAQ article.

Answer (score 1):

Users have the ability to block apps from accessing any of your data, or certain types just certain types of their data. You can set this from the FB front end at **Privacy Settings -> Apps, Games & Websites -> How people bring your info to apps they use**.

The API filters these items for visibility after your query is executed. There is no way to see what is missing.